# ¿IDE0017 C# La inicialización del objeto se puede simplificar?

Tags: c#, unity

Estoy recibiendo esta advertencia (IDE0017 C# La inicialización del objeto se puede simplificar). Pero  no veo la forma de como simplifircalo. Todo lo que intento me da error. ¿Alguien sabe como simplificarlo?

El código es el siguiente:

```
public class ObjectAndControler<ControlerClassName> : System.Object  where ControlerClassName : Component
{
    public GameObject gameObject;
    public ControlerClassName controler;
}

//-------------------------------------------------
public static ObjectAndControler<ClassName> GetObjectAndControler<ClassName>(string gameObjectName) where ClassName : Component
{
    ObjectAndControler<ClassName> oac = new ObjectAndControler<ClassName>();

    oac.gameObject = GameObject.Find(gameObjectName);

    if (oac.gameObject == null) return null;

    oac.controler = oac.gameObject.GetComponent<ClassName>();            

    return oac;
}
```

La advertencia me está saliendo para esta línea:

```
 ObjectAndControler<ClassName> oac = new ObjectAndControler<ClassName>();
```

Muchas gracias!!

Comment: En la lamparita amarilla, te da las opciones sobre esa linea

Comment: Si, lo hice, pero no salía nada que me ayudara... Por suerte el compañero Lobos me ha dado la solución al problema!! Un Saludo Ramiro!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto puede ser un equivalente que atiende esa advertencia:

```
    var gameObject = GameObject.Find(gameObjectName);
    if (gameObject == null) return null;
            
    return new ObjectAndControler<ClassName>{
         gameObject = gameObject,
         controler = gameObject.GetComponent<ClassName>()
    };
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias Lobos!! Eso funcionó!! La advertencia desapareció!! Saludos!!